# Probability involving intersecting roads

Tags: probability

[Image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1pJK.png)

A person enters at A and after reaching the point of intersection ,he chooses a
direction randomly (including the possibility of turning around ). If the person
reaches an exit then he cannot turn around.(From the respective junctions if a
person goes towards either A or B or C or D then he cannot turn around)

We have to find the Probability that he will exit at A

[This is my working to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjPu7.jpg)(If the person is standing on n ,Pn is the probability that it reaches 1)

My answer is coming out to be 13/21 but answer given is 7/15

Please let me know if i have done something wrong.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $k\in\{1,2,3\}$, let $p_k$ be the probability of exiting at $A$,

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$[image]

given that the current position is $k$ steps away from $A$.

Then we get the system
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
p_1&=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}p_2\\[4pt]
p_2&=\frac{1}{3}p_1+\frac{1}{3}p_3\\[4pt]
p_3&=\frac{2}{3}p_2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
of $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns.

Solving the system yields $p_1={\large{\frac{7}{15}}}$.

If you compare your work with the above solution, you should be able to find your error.

Comment: Thanks , found my mistake